# Passing all state properties to function except one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to pass all state except one property? I mean I have component which looks like that, and I wish to pass to redux function this.props.editAnimal() all state except property "submitted", is it possible to somehow exclude one state property and pass all the others?

```
export class EditAnimal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            animalName: '',
            animalNumber: '',
            animalChip: '',
            animalAge: '',
            extraInfo: '',
            submited: false
        }
    }

handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const id = this.props.id
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        this.props.editAnimal(id, this.state)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Here is one:

```
const tempState = {...this.state};
delete tempState.submited;
this.props.editAnimal(id, tempState);
```

First, this creates a copy of the state by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the state into a temporary variable `tempState`. Then, we remove the property we don't want from the temporary variable  with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

<sup>*Sidenote: you have misspelled "submitted", it's with double "t".*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you are transpiling your code with babel, you can destructure the state and copy the variables you only care about:

```
const { submited, ...editAnimalParams } = this.state;
this.props.editAnimal(id, editAnimalParams)
```

You can see [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20x%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%203%2C%20z%3A26%7D%3B%0Alet%20%7Bb%2C%20...y%7D%20%3D%20x%3B) what babel transpiles down to, but basically skips any keys you don't want to copy.

If you're not using babel (probably unlikely), then you can do a bit more verbosely but wouldn't need babel:

```
const editAnimalParams = Object.assign({}, this.state);
delete editAnimalParams.submited;
this.props.editAnimal(id, editAnimalParams)
```